# Derivation of propositional logic

Tags: logic

So, I'm struggling to derive the wanted conclusion for a problem.

P->Q
P->~S
R->~Q
~Q->S

---

~(P&R)

I've been trying to sort this out, and have been unable to.

Comment: What is that you want to prove?

Comment: What inference rules do you have available to use? There are many different derivation systems, and they differ in terms of what rules they have, so we'll need to know what system you are working with in order to help out.  Also, can you show us what work you have done and where you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}[t]
1.&\\2.&\\3.&\\4.&\\5.&\\6.&\\7.&\\8.&\\9.&\\10.&\\11.&
\end{aligned}
\quad
\begin{aligned}[t]
&P \to Q\\
&P \to \neg S \\
&R \to \neg Q \\
&\neg Q \to S \\
&P \wedge R\\
&P \\
&Q \\
&R \\
&\neg Q \\
&Q \wedge \neg Q\\
&\neg(P \wedge R)
\end{aligned}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}[t]
&\text{A}\\&\text{A}\\&\text{A}\\&\text{A}\\&\text{PA}\\&\text{5, Simp}\\&\text{1, 6, MP}\\&\text{5, Simp}\\&\text{3, 8, MP}\\&\text{7, 9, Conj}\\&\text{5$-$10, RAA}
\end{aligned}
$$

**Notation:** A for assumption; PA for provisional assumption; Simp for simplification; MP for *modus ponens*; Conj for conjunction; RAA for *reductio ad absurdum*.

Answer (score 0):

We can restate the conditions as follows.

P implies Q

P implies not S

Q implies not R

not S implies Q

Hence, $P\rightarrow Q\land(\neg S) \rightarrow Q\land Q\iff Q \rightarrow \neg R$

Therefore P implies not R. In general,

$p \rightarrow q \iff q \lor \neg p$

Therefore $P\rightarrow \neg R \iff \neg R \lor \neg P \iff \neg(P\land R)$

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the first and third hypotheses are sufficient for your conclusion. Since $R\rightarrow \neg Q$ is the same as $Q\rightarrow \neg R$, so this with $P\rightarrow Q$ gives $P\rightarrow \neg R$ which is the same as $\neg P\vee \neg R$ i.e. $\neg(P\wedge R)$ by DeMorgan.